# Is it possible download file with Python ftplib at the same time as retrieving file list information from the list function?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have a scenario that looks something like below. My goal is to print out the lines of the file that I'm retrieving from the Python ftplib `retrlines("LIST")` function. Any help is appreciated.

```
class FTP:

    def __init__(self, hostName, userName, passWord, encoding=None):
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP(host=hostName, user=userName, passwd=passWord)
        self.defaultEncoding = self.ftp.encoding
        self.ftp.encoding = encoding or self.ftp.encoding
    
    def writeTest(self, fileName, func):
        self.ftp.retrlines(f'RETR {fileName}', func)

    def getFileInformation(self, func=None):

        encoding = self.ftp.encoding
        self.ftp.encoding = self.defaultEncoding
        self.ftp.retrlines('LIST', lambda row: func(self._returnFileInformation(row)))
        self.ftp.encoding = encoding


class FileProcessor:

    def __init__(self, processingFunction: Callable, output: Callable):
        self.processingFunction = processingFunction
        self.output = output
        self.fileCounter = 0

    def processFile(self, file: FileInformation):
        if self.processingFunction(file):
            self.output(file)
            self.fileCounter += 1

def __len__(self):
    return self.fileCounter

lastReadTime = datetime(2020, 10, 29, 0, 0, 0)
ftp = FTP(hostName=hostName, userName=userName, passWord=passWord, encoding='utf-16')
processor = FileProcessor(lambda file: file.timeStamp > lastReadTime, lambda file: ftp.writeTest(file.name, lambda line: print(line)))
ftp.getFileInformation(processor.processFile)
```

The `getFileInformation` just returns the values from the `retrlines` `LIST` function in a nice formatted class that has the name, size, etc. I'm just trying to print the lines of the files, as I'm getting the file names from `retrlines('LIST')`. If I retrieve the file names first, and then process the files after, I have no problem. If I try to do it all at once I get an error that looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot download files, while you are still downloading a directory listing using the same connection. That's not possible with the FTP protocol, no matter what FTP library you are using. In terms of the ftplib API: you cannot call back to the `FTP` class (you cannot call `FTP.retrlines('RETR ...')`), while another method (`FTP.retrlines('LIST ...')`) is still executing.

Either:

- Open two connections, one for the listing and one for file downloads.
- Or stick with *"retrieve the file names first, and then process the files after"* – I do not see what's wrong about it.